# Hide element on weekends

Tags: javascript

I have some HTML/javascript elements that I want to only be visible on Mon - Fri

How can I achieve this? I only know how to hide it on specific dates with this code

```
window.setInterval(function(){

  var current = new Date();
  var expiry  = new Date("October 30, 2014 12:00:00")

  if(current.getTime()>expiry.getTime()){
    $('#div1').hide();
  }

}, 3000);

$('#one').show();
```

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: Just a note - anyone with minimal JS knowledge will be able to bypass this element hiding... Also people without JS enabled will not "benefit" from your logic here.

Comment: @Lix true on the bypass, but IMHO a browser without JS these days can barely be considered functional given how many sites now utterly depend on JS.

Comment: @Alnitak - not a browser without JS but a user that has disabled JS for security reasons (I guess that becomes the users problem because as you say a browser without JS is borderline functional). My main point here is that "hiding elements" doesn't guarantee (at all) that users will not be able to see the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the day of the week, using [Date.getDay()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp). Hide it for day 6 and 0 then.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the [JS Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to get the day of the week

```
var DayOfTheWeek = new Date().getDay();  //0=Sun, 1=Mon, ..., 6=Sat
```

then, based on the day, show the element

```
if(DayOfTheWeek == 6 || DayOfTheWeek == 0){
    $('#div1').hide();
} else {
    $('#div1').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `Date.getDay()` will be your friend. It returns a number for a each day of the week. Sunday => 0; Monday => 1; ...

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
```

So you can easily check if the day is between 1 and 5. If yes then display your stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function.

```
 if(current.getDay() == 6 || current.getDay() == 0){
    $('#div1').hide();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the LOLs, here's a one-liner demonstrating how you can call a jQuery function by (variable) name, and also use modulo arithmetic to avoid two separate calls to `.getDay()`:

```
$('#div1')[(date.getDay() + 6) % 7 < 5 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

The modulo arithmetic works thus:

```
Sun = 0, + 6 =  6, mod 7 = 6
Mon = 1, + 6 =  7, mod 7 = 0
...
Fri = 5, + 6 = 11, mod 7 = 4
Sat = 6, + 6 = 12, mod 7 = 5
```

Hence Monday to Friday give 0 .. 4, and Saturday and Sunday give 5 and 6, allowing a single comparison to check for weekend vs weekday.

For posterity, here's a potentially useful helper function:

```
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'isWeekday', { value: function() {
    return (this.getDay() + 6) % 7 <= 4;
}));
```

usage:

```
if (mydate.isWeekday()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more maintainable version. The element `#div1` should be displayed by default and only hidden if the appropriate days are detected.

```
var days_to_hide = {
  0 : "Sunday",
  6 : "Saturday"
}

var today = new Date().getDay();
if( typeof days_to_hide[ today ] !== "undefined" ){
  $('#div1').hide();
}
```

The reason that it is more maintainable is that you can freely edit the `days_to_hide` definition without having to modify the conditional expression that actually performs the `hide()` command.

Answer (score -2):

try this code

```
var d = new Date();
if(d.getDay() == 6 || d.getDay() == 7)
{
   $('#div1').hide();
}
```

Comment: `getDay()` returns 0 .. 6, and _never_ returns a string!

Comment: He is, however, only loosely comparing both strings `==`, not `===`, so it'll work...

Comment: @somethinghere yup, I'd have given him another -1 for that if I could - _intentionally_ using a loose comparison with a string against a function that only returns numbers is really sloppy.

Comment: @alnitak Jup, true. TBH though, every answer on this page should be down voted because of this as none use `===`, cause even loosely comparing new `Date().getDay() == 6` is just as bad.

Comment: @somethinghere my answer uses no equality operators, loose or otherwise ;-)  And yes, I agree with you re: use of loose comparisons.   JS would be a better language without them.

Comment: @alnitak Ah yes I didn't mention the **ONE** answer that didn't need down voting. Should've checked the name on it. It's quite a complex way to solve the probe;em algorhytmically but interesting nonetheless :)